# Add an index sequentially from lowest data attribute in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have the following code and am trying to add an index to each item in sequential number order:

```
<div class="item" data-id='1'>Option 1</div>
<div class="item" data-id='19'>Option 19</div>
<div class="item" data-id='5'>Option 5</div>  
<div class="item" data-id='39'>Option 39</div>

$('.item').each(function (i) {
    $(this).attr('data-new-id', 'item-' + (i + 1));
});
```

This outputs as:

```
<div class="item" data-id="1" data-new-id="item-1">Option 1</div>
<div class="item" data-id="19" data-new-id="item-2">Option 19</div>
<div class="item" data-id="5" data-new-id="item-3">Option 5</div>  
<div class="item" data-id="39" data-new-id="item-4">Option 39</div>
```

Ideal output is:

```
<div class="item" data-id="1" data-new-id="item-1">Option 1</div>
<div class="item" data-id="19" data-new-id="item-3">Option 19</div>
<div class="item" data-id="5" data-new-id="item-2">Option 5</div>  
<div class="item" data-id="39" data-new-id="item-4">Option 39</div>
```

So that the order stays the same but the script finds the data-id and adds a new sequence from 1 from lowest to highest.

Create a JSfiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/wwwredback/rbo1ukxo/1/

Comment: To achieve this you would need to first `sort()` the elements by their `data-id` attribute, then perform your `each()` loop

Comment: Thanks Rory, that's a great help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Rory said in his comment, you need to sort the `data-id`s first and then assign new `data` attribute to the elements.

See below

```js
var item = $(".item")
item.sort(function(a, b) {
  return ($(a).data('id')) > ($(b).data('id'));
}).each(function(i) {
  $(this).attr('data-new-id', 'item-' + (i + 1));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item" id="1" data-id='1'>Option 1</div>
<div class="item" id="5" data-id='19'>Option 19</div>
<div class="item" id="3" data-id='5'>Option 5</div>
<div class="item" id="2" data-id='39'>Option 39</div>
```

Output

```
<div class="item" id="1" data-id="1" data-new-id="item-1">Option 1</div>
<div class="item" id="5" data-id="19" data-new-id="item-3">Option 19</div>
<div class="item" id="3" data-id="5" data-new-id="item-2">Option 5</div>
<div class="item" id="2" data-id="39" data-new-id="item-4">Option 39</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. That's perfect. Thanks